# Retrive array from php with ajax and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I'm trying to create a line chart using chart.js and I want to pass the axis (the labels in this case) from a php file, this:

```
<?php  
$new_labels = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July');
echo json_encode($new_labels);
?>
```

with this javascript:

```
         function retrieveLabel(label) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: "sys/class/profilesGraphHandler.php",
                  type: "GET",
                  success: function (data) {
                      label(data);
                  }

              });
          }

          retrieveLabel(function (output) { new_labels = output, console.log(new_labels) });
```

The console shows me that there are 7 elements in the array I retrieve from the php file but the labels are not shown anyway.

```
var areaChartData = { labels: new_labels , dataset....};
```

How can I pass the "new_labels" from the ajax to the labels of the areaChartData ?

Comment: The code that is using the response from the AJAX should be used inside the `success` callback i.e. after the completion of the Asynchronous call.

Comment: show us your console result.

Comment: the console result is only a number, 7

Comment: Why are you doing console.log(new_labels.length) ? Dont put .length if you want actual results. It's outputting 7 because you have 7 elements in your object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript Hope this helps

Comment: I modified the javascript and now in the console there is the exact array I passed in the php, but I'm not able to assign it to "labels"

Comment: please give output of data variable in get in success function.

Comment: and exactly how can I do it?

Comment: add a `console && console.log(data);` inside the success callback

Comment: thanks to all guys but I resolved using this: '<?php echo $js_cols; ?>'

Comment: check once http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/array2json/

Comment: put your solution in your answers so that all can see the solution.